# How to insert only date into database

Tags: c#

I am inserting some date values into database. I am using `System.DateTime.ToString();` function.This function inserts date and time together but I don't want time .How can I save date only in database
my button click is

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = CheckBox1.Checked ? 1 : 0;
    try
    {
         string str=mas.empdetadd(ddid.SelectedItem.Text,Convert.ToDateTime(txtdate.Text));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read this article: [Custom Date and Time format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) P.s. Disturbing question asking about inserting date as string but in code converting string to date time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
str=mas.empdetadd(ddid.SelectedItem.Text,Convert.ToDateTime(txtdate.Text).Date);
```

if the method accept the DataTime type

Comment: Nobody knows: 1. What type of field you have in db. 2. What your empdetadd function does. 3. Where it showing? and so on. Only fortune-teller can tell us what you doing, what you have and what you want :)

Comment: Reniuz.Oh I am sorry i have a filed join date with "date" datatype in database and i have a datetime parameter in class "datetime date"

Comment: [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can go with this:

```
Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now).Date.ToString("d");
```

Comment: This way (.ToString("d") will effectively remove the time part

Comment: Steve,I have a text box "txtdate.text" how i should pass that text box value in this method?

Comment: If your txtdate.text as the correct format, you can pass it this way:  Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToDateTime(txtdate.text).Date.ToString("d"))

Comment: For example, txtdate.text could be "2014.09.22"

Comment: Steve,Ya i applied the second method.It insert only date into databse but when I displays this databse data in a grid view it shows like"26-Sep-14 12:00:00 AM".How it is like this?

Comment: Maybe your field in your database isn't DATE but DATETIME and check the date format you pass to your gridview to find a solution

Answer (score 0):

The DateTime type always store time however you can truncate the data by calling ToShortDateString() on the datetime which more or less means that hours, minutes and seconds will be set to 0.

Answer (score -1):

If you mean in the code you can use ToShortDateString() instead of ToString();

Comment: Karsten yes,how it is possible

Comment: DateTime shortDateTime = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Parse(ddid.SelectedItem.Text).ToShortDateString());